# HSQLDB & Hibernate: how to auto create database once

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I have an app that requires some data stored but not that much. Is just some user preferences. HSQLDB fits the purpose as it provides fast access and since I'm on Jboss it is already there

The problem is that if I use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto create, it will destroy what was there before, if there is a server restart or something like it.

Can something be done? Or should I just tell the customer to install a db and run an script as usual?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is best to have script. Autogeneration is more development time toy. You can also run script automatically as a part of deployment, if there is no needs for DBA to affect it.

If you want to use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto, then option to use is *update*, it will create missing tables (in your case all of them) in first run, and do no changes in later runs because database schema is already up to date.

Comment: thanks, my interest with all this was that I really liked the In-Process mode of HSQLDB, whats your opinion on using an script, but with HSQLDB on server mode? The information is not a lot, just to keep users from retyping some config stuff